# Continue command on a new line

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sh

To improve the readability of my code, I want to go to a new line in the code but I do not want the compiler to treat is as a different line of command. How do I do this?

```
python file_a.py file_b.py
file_c.py file_d.py
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to improve the readability of the command that calls `python` to execute the `.py` files, not the code within the `.py` files?

Comment: Yes, improve the readability of the bash file which calls the python code.

Answer (score 7):

You do this by **escaping the newline character**, add a backslash `\` directly before the line break:

```
python file_a.py file_b.py \
file_c.py file_d.py
```

You may indent the second line to further improve readability:

```
python file_a.py file_b.py \
  file_c.py file_d.py
```

Comment: I just tried this but it gives the following error: ./python_bash.sh: line 4: file_c.py file_d..py: command not found

Comment: @user45524 This should work. You are putting the slash immediately before the linebreak? It won't work if there is a space after it.

Comment: I think i understand the problem, It seems that I have Windows style line endings (\r\n) - I need to change them to unix style (\n)